# Separate values of an associative array with a comma

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a better way to separate the values of an array than this one?

```
<?php 
    $q = "SELECT * FROM students LEFT JOIN Groepen ON Groepen.groep_id=students.groep WHERE students.uid = '$user[uid]'AND students.groep = '$groep[groep_id]' ORDER BY st_last ASC";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    while($students_in_group = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
?>

<?php echo $students_in_group['st_first']." ".$students_in_group['st_last'].", "; ?>
<?php } ?> </p>
```

The code above also adds a comma after the last name.

I would also like to send an email to all the members of a group using the $students_in_group[email]. I suppose that also there I will have to separate their email addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `while()` loop, add/append the names in an array. Then after coming out of the loop, use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to concatenate the names with commas, like this:

```
<?php 
    $q = "SELECT * FROM students LEFT JOIN Groepen ON Groepen.groep_id=students.groep WHERE students.uid = '$user[uid]'AND students.groep = '$groep[groep_id]' ORDER BY st_last ASC";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    $names = array();
    while($students_in_group = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { 
        $names[] = $students_in_group['st_first']." ".$students_in_group['st_last'];
    } 
    echo implode(",", $names);
?>
```

Comment: OP still didn't respond to your comment yet under your other answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40950434/ - wondering if they will and for this one too and if they know how Stack rolls *lol*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, sometimes it's difficult to get them rolled on the same track. *sigh* But we sill keep doing our volunteership i.e. help them in resolving their issues. :-)

Comment: Update: *"I would also like to send an email to all the members"* - OP just posted a new question. Having given them the solution for it also would have most likely avoided it ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/q/40963402/ I said "probably" ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's like one answer leads to another question, (re)searching/trying-out-yourself for a solution has become *too hard* these days. ;-)

Comment: I know; it wouldn't have taken much to Google that. I'm sure I could come up with a lot of Q&A's in under 5 seconds flat ;-)